# RabbitMQ Memory Usage grows too high

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, erlang, rabbitmq

I am experiencing a problem with rabbitmq 2.8.5. There are 3 queues that messages are published to and they are consumed relatively quickly by the consumers. So the queues aren't big at all. 
There are 3 exchanges one for each queue. 
However the memory on rabbitmq continues to grow.

I tried running two different commands to understand what was happening to the memory however  rabbitmq would hang when i run them.

```
rabbitmqctl eval '[[{pid, R}, M | process_info(R)] || {M, R} <- 
lists:sublist(lists:reverse(lists:sort([{process_info(P, memory), P} || 
P <- erlang:processes()])), 10)].'

'lists:sublist(lists:reverse(lists:sort([{process_info(Pid,memory), Pid, 
sys:get_status(Pid,infinity)} || Pid <- [element(7, Q) || Q <- 
rabbit_amqqueue:list()]])), 10).'
```

I then tried to observe the memory usage on the erlang vm that rabbitmq is running on and it 9235 (I think its in bytes).

So if the queues and exchanges aren't large and Erlang Ram is far below that of rabbitmq what could be the cause?

As the Memory usage continues to grow it eventually reaches the max memory water mark and no more publishing can occur.

Comment: check the message size and the time the message spends in the queue before the consumer gets it. Also, what technique are you using to fetch messages: `polling` or `subscription` ? If the processes in your middle ware are polling the server for the messages, then depending on the poll rate and the number of polling threads, RABBITMQ will be accepting many incoming requests and hence using lots of memory as compared to a subscription technique. With subscribers, we noticed that RABBITMQ used less resources.

Comment: The consumers are subscription based. But even if that were the case i would suspect when traffic is low my RAM should shrink however it never reduces in size.

Comment: Now, i think that there are a couple of `disc_copies` mnesia tables used by `RABBITMQ`. Also, it depends on the messaging technique. If the receiver of messages does not send an `ACK` for them, i guess that `RABBITMQ` retains a copy in the database. Ensure that for each message received, you send an `ACK` for it. Then, also, are your queues `durable` ? messages `durable` or the exchanges `durable` ? you see, `RABBITMQ` has lots of concepts. Try this, make the messages and queues `un-durable` and ensure that every message has an `ACK` sent for it. How many `exchanges` or `queues` do you have ?

Comment: I have checked and I do send an ack on consume.
channel.basciAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag false)
as my thread is consuming the messages they move to the unacked state before being removed i am guessing when the thread acknowledges. 

The Queues and Exchanges  are durable 

I am a  bit hesitant on setting the queues and messages to un-durable as it is a somewhat an production environment.

3 exchanges, 3 queues each exchange has one queue.

The consumers are multiple threads I'm not sure if this has any baring.

Comment: how did you check that `RABBITMQ` is consuming the memory. look at this: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ and http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html

Comment: Ok i never knew about this and it is very useful information i always wondered what that row +/-  meant when i run the free -g. But i don't believe this to be the case.

Rabbitmq max memory watermark is set to 0.4, so my OVERALL RAM use is not excessive its just the RAM AVAILABLE TO RABBITMQ.

I checked from the web interface that should the section to be red and showing the fraction in use to be the entire RAM available and two after while rabbitmq starts blocking connections.

Can threading have a baring on this? 

i.e. I want to check how many threads connect to rabbitmq, or is this a waste

Comment: i doubt that threading has a bearing on this. Could you print us the output of your: `rabbitmqctl status` as documented here: `http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory-use.html`  ?

Comment: `{memory,
     [{total,6296577000},
      {processes,1602867472},
      {processes_used,1602621768},
      {system,4693709528},
      {atom,1539145},
      {atom_used,1523406},
      {binary,1083087968},
      {code,13510651},
      {ets,3148715088}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.3999999999763093},
 {vm_memory_limit,10130569625},
 {disk_free_limit,1000000000},
 {disk_free,7443308544},`

Above is what i get when i check rabbitmq status. 
What exactly is system? Becuase it is consuming 4GB and process and process_used take about 1.6GB each. 
Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your per message sizes as payload. All message will be stored in the memory.

If it is too big, it is better to redesign the messsage.

Comment: The messages aren't big at all. And even when the queues are empty the RAM is still remians what it once was. I.e. My RAM will never reduce in size it can only grow.